# document.getElementsByClassName - How to get elements having ONLY the specified Class - no Secondary or Subclasses

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

How do I locate ONLY the elements having the class "Cover" but not the elements having more classes than Cover.  Using getElementsByClassName I was not able to discover a way for it to NOT also find elements having the "Cover" class and also the "place-holder" class.

Also I question what the correct terminology is for the 2nd class of "place-holder".  Do we refer to that class as a subclass or is it simply just a 2nd class on the element?

```
<div>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1" aria-label="First Name: firstName" style="height: 38px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 274.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="2" aria-label="Last Name: lastName" style="height: 38px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 314.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="3" aria-label="Suffix: Suffix" style="height: 38px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 354.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover place-holder" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="10" style="height: 34px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 634.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="20" aria-label="Gender: Gender" style="height: 108px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 1619.75px;"></a>
</div>
```

Simple Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Cover");

// finds five elements.  How do I tell it to find ONLY elements having the Cover Class?
```

Comment: Would it always just be `place-holder` as the second class of two? You could use `document.querySelectorAll('.cover:not(.place-holder)')`.

Comment: I was just trying querySelectorAll but was running into the same issue.  I am new to that syntax... `:not(.class).`  Awesome.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). It basically takes CSS selectors (of which [`:not()` is a "pseudo-class"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)) so it's a little more versatile than methods like `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply:

```js
const onlyCover = document.querySelectorAll('[class="Cover"]');

onlyCover.forEach( elm =>
  {
  console.log( elm.className, elm.textContent );
  })
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="Cover" >aa</a>
  <a href="#" class="Cover" >bb</a>
  <a href="#" class="Cover" >cc</a>
  <a href="#" class="Cover place-holder" >dd</a>
  <a href="#" class="Cover" >ee</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let elems = [...document.getElementsByClassName('Cover')]
  .filter(i=>i.classList.length===1)
  
console.log(elems)
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1" aria-label="First Name: firstName" style="height: 38px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 274.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="2" aria-label="Last Name: lastName" style="height: 38px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 314.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="3" aria-label="Suffix: Suffix" style="height: 38px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 354.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover place-holder" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="10" style="height: 34px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 634.375px;"></a>
    <a class="Cover" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="20" aria-label="Gender: Gender" style="height: 108px; left: 26px; width: 1035px; top: 1619.75px;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The only piece I am failing to understand are how the ... prefixing `...document.getEl` works?  I see that if I don't apply the 3 periods I get different returns.  Does that have something to do with the Array and how it is being created?  Hmmm...

Comment: @CodeNovice `getElementsByClassName` returns an "array-like" live HTML collection of child elements. To be able to use `filter` on them the collection needs to be coerced to an actual array (with all its accompanying methods) and this is achieved with [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Note: `forEach` will work on node lists and HTML collections _without_ the coercion, but it's the only array method is available.

Comment: @CodeNovice getElementsByClassName  returns a DOMTokenList object, which is not an array. However, it implements the `@@iterator` method, which means that the spread operator will be able to iterate over it to extract all values into the array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols